# How does this clojure digits function work?

Tags: clojure, digits

I'm working through the 4clojure problems. I came across this answer for #120, which I would have totally never thought of on my own:

```
 (fn sum-square [coll]
  (let [digits (fn [n] (map #(- (int %) 48) (str n)))
    square #(* % %)
    sum-digits (fn [n] (reduce + (map square (digits n))))]
(count (filter #(< % (sum-digits %)) coll))))
```

The part I'm really trying to understand is how the digits part of it works.

```
(fn [n] (map #(- (int %) 48) (str n))
```

I'm really confused about how

```
(map #(- (int %) 48) "10")
```

returns

```
(1 0)
```

Can you please explain how this works? I'm confused about why n has to be turned into a string, and why it's then turned back into an integer, and why it has 48 subtracted. I'm sure there must be some really neat trick I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"10" in the context of map can be treated as a seq of chars(in this case \1 and \0)
then `int` converts say \1 to ascii 49, and \0 to ascii 48
then `- 48` converts 49 to 1 and 48 to 0